# should custom action filter inherit FilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As I know each action filter should inherit IActionFilter and FilterAttribute.
For example:

```
public class ActionSpeedProfilerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter 
{ 
     public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
     { 
         throw new NotImplementedException(); 
     }
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
     { 
         throw new NotImplementedException(); 
     } 
}
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/976/aspnet-mvc-custom-action-filter

But in Microsoft tutorial of ASP.NET .Core we have examples without FilterAttribute:

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // do something before the action executes
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // do something after the action executes
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters

So should we inherit FilterAttribute or not ?

Comment: If you want to create an ActionFilter just inherit ActionFilterAttribute which already implements IActionFilter-interface. Then override for example OnActionExecuting-method for your needs.

Comment: @Esko ok but I would like to know also what is going on with FilterAttrubute when I use IActionFilter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `FilterAttribute` if you just want to add the filter globally (in `FilterConfig`), like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new SampleActionFilter());
    }
}
```

...which would make this filter to be executed for every action, since it implements `IActionFilter`.

Now, if you want to create a filter which could be used for specific actions, then it would be better inheriting `FilterAttribute`, because it would allow you to use it like this:

```
public class LogActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter 
{ 
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
    { 
        // log something about the action...
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
    { 

    } 
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [LogAction]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So in this case, instead of executing it for every action, you can choose what actions to execute that filter with **Attributes**.

---

As a sidenote, there is also a `IResultFilter` interface which works like `IActionFilter`, it triggers when the result is being executed and after it executes (likewise `IActionFilter`, but for result instead of action).

Doing this:

```
public class LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }

}
```

Is the same as:

```
public class LogActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }

}
```

...because `ActionFilterAttribute` does exactly the same thing:

```
public abstract class ActionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @MrChudz you asked *So should we inherit FilterAttribute or not ?*. I answered that. Now, you ask if you should inherit `FilterAttribute` but it doesn't even exist in the project you are using because its core, so it doesn't make sense asking if you should inherit a class that doesn't exist in the framework you're using. What do you need?

Comment: If you just need the filter globally, you don't need to inherit any built-in filter classes, like `ActionFilterAttribute` and `ResultFilterAttribute`. If you want to use it like an attribute in your actions, so the filter is executed only for specific actions, make your filter inherit `ActionFilterAttribute` and override the proper methods you want. Is this the answer you were looking for?